# playsinline not working for video on iOS?

Tags: ios, html5-video, playback

I have a site that uses a video with the following code:

```
<video class="hero-video-actual" autoplay loop muted playsinline>
  <source src="/content/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I need the video to autoplay on iOS. It autoplays just fine on Android and desktop, but not iOS. I'm not sure why. Everything I see online says that if you use the `playsinline` attribute, you should be good. But it's not working for me, and I know of no way to inspect the browser console in iOS.

Comment: Coincidently a similar question was just asked: see here for reference to iOS autoplay policies: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62794581/334402 Your example appears to meet the guidelines. Maybe you can share an example and we can look more deeply?

Comment: @Mick I would like to share an example because I've tried numerous solutions which all should seem to work, yet are not working. My site is built using BigCommerce – maybe that has something to do with it? I don't know if I'm at liberty to share the site URL publicly in this comment, but is there a way I could send it to you privately?

Comment: It might be better if you could create a simple example using some non sensitive video and share that - then the wider community here can view and respond also.

Comment: I also encountered this issue on iOS 14, `playsinline` is not working. 
Do you have any further progress on this issue? @GDP2

Comment: I found that "Low Power Mode" enabled will not autoplay video even with `autoplay`, `playsinline` and `muted`.

Comment: This really helped me.  "Low Power Mode" disables all playsinline video.
Thanks @JohnWong

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your Code like this:

```
<video 
  class="hero-video-actual" 
  autoplay 
  loop 
  muted 
  playsinline 
  src="/content/video.mp4" 
  type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

the "`src-path`" dont need a own tag, you should include it in the `<video>` tag

Comment: This doesn't address the question