# 2020: iOS Safari Video Autoplay Options?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari, html5-video

All of my research and effort has been hitting a wall so far in this regard: Is there any way to make video autoplay on Safari in iOS currently?

Some have mentioned video transcoding or using `playsinline` (which works on Android), but nothing has worked for iOS / Safari.

Comment: Apple have done a pretty good job of blocking this in most scenarios (conserves battery and bandwidth) until the user interacts with an element... can't think of a reliable working example that I've seen for a while

Answer (score 4):

I believe the following is still the current picture for iOS:

> elements will now honor the autoplay attribute, for elements which meet the following conditions:
>
> - elements will be allowed to autoplay without a user gesture if their source media contains no audio tracks.
> - elements will also be allowed to autoplay without a user gesture.
> - If a  element gains an audio track or becomes un-muted without a user gesture, playback will pause.
> - elements will only begin playing when visible on-screen such as when they are scrolled into the viewport, made visible through CSS, and inserted into the DOM.
> - elements will pause if they become non-visible, such as by being scrolled out of the viewport.

Source: https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/

This also requires that the video element has the `playsinline` attribute.

So there is support for autoplay video, but it is limited so may not meet your particular needs.

One other note - if your use case is for a web view rather than a regular browser, then you have more control. See the documentation for `wkwebviewconfiguration` and in particular `mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback` here:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebviewconfiguration